# using Count(*) result field in same query in a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was trying use result of table count in same query to compare it with a constant value. Is there any possible way I can do it? I know that we can't use ALIAS name to compare it but I could not figure out in which way I can compare it.

```
Select count(*) as totalcount from table1 where totalcount = 2201;
```

Comment: You should use HAVING clause: ...FROMtable1 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2201;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Select (case when count(*) = 2201 then 'correct' else 'wrong' end) as
from table1;
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the semantic model defined in the SQL standards, the WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT clause and therefore many DBMS do not allow you to refer to things in the SELECT list from the WHERE clause.

A workaround would be to repeat the expression instead of trying to refer to it by name:

```
select count(*) as totalcount from table1 having count(*) = 2201;
```

However, such a query would not make a whole lot of sense. If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish then you can get a more helpful answer...

For example, if you want to see whether a table has a given number of rows then you can use

```
if (select count(*) from table1) = 2201
   print 'Bingo!';
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you're asking for, but it doesn't make much sense...

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalcount
FROM table1 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2201;
```

You use the `HAVING` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause when you want to qualify aggregate values.

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregate functions is not allowed in where condition, you are looking for Having

```
Select count(*) as totalcount from table1 having totalcount = 2201;
```

It will work but it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your are not satisfied with the other answers the other way you can use it as shown below.

```
declare @tblRCount int = 0
declare @CountToCheck int = 2201
Select @tblRCount = count(*) as totalcount from table1 where <columnName> = <values>
if (@tblRCount = @CountToCheck)
begin
  Select <your column list here>
end
else
begin
  Select <your column list here>
end
```